# Twitter Card Validation

Tags: validation, twitter, meta, twitter-card

Can anybody see whats wrong with this code, to say why this isnt validating using

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator

[image: http://agoraclothing.com/shop/hats/beanies/agora-black-beanie.html]

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="product">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Agora_snapbacks">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Agora_snapbacks">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Agora Black Beanie">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="View our varied collection of beanies by Agora">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://agoraclothing.com/images/detailed/1/LOGOB_BLACK.JPG">
<meta name="twitter:data1" content="29.99">
<meta name="twitter:label1" content="Price">
<meta name="twitter:data2" content="United Kingdom">
<meta name="twitter:label2" content="Locaion">
```

http://agoraclothing.com/shop/hats/beanies/agora-black-beanie.html

Comment: I can't access to the url - 'http://agoraclothing.com/shop/hats/beanies/agora-black-beanie.html'. Is it public?

Comment: Yeah sorry we're developing it at the moment as this question was asked a while ago, and haven't looked at it since.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be in the price/data1 field.  You may have to add the pound symbol before 29.99.  I can't be positive but it's worth a try.  --David

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll give this a look later tonight :)